# Need Help With Integrating A Function

Tags: calculus, integration

I'am trying to integrate the following function$$\int \frac{2}{(v-1)^2}dv$$
So far I've tried $u$ substitution.Here are the steps.Let $$u = (v-1)^2$$  then$$\frac{du}{dv} = 2v-2$$ solving for $dv$ $$dv = \frac{1}{2(v-1)}du$$
This doesn't seem to me a sensible way of working out this integration.I'am stuck Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=v-1$, $du=dv$. Then

$$\int\frac{dv}{(v-1)^2}=\int\frac{du}{u^2}.$$

I'm sure you can finish, now!

Comment: It's $\frac{-2}{v-1} + C$.Yeah Bruno Rocks!

Comment: I do my best! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Letting $u=v-1$ makes the integral $\int2u^{-2}du$, which I bet you can do on your own.

Always consider the possibility of the simplest substitutions (e.g. linear) before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the power rule for integration,
$$\int x^n\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\quad (n\neq 1)\quad ?$$
There is a different $u$-substitution you can make where you can apply it.

Comment: yes i'am familiar